# Unable to build docker image due to connection timeout error

Tags: docker

I'm unable to build my docker image as it keeps erroring out with a timeout error. I'm working on a system that doesn't allow http connection. I tried using `HTTP_PROXY` & `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables in the Dockerfile but it didn't help.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM conda/miniconda3:latest

RUN mkdir mlflow

WORKDIR /mlflow
   
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    libpq-dev

RUN pip install -U pip && \
    pip install psycopg2 mlflow boto3


EXPOSE 5000

CMD mlflow server \
    --host 0.0.0.0 \
    --port 5000 \
    --backend-store-uri "postgresql+psycopg2://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@postgresql:5432/mlflowdb" \
    --default-artifact-root "s3://bucket-eb84c612/"
```

**Error**

```
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to 151.101.210.132:80 (151.101.210.132), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not connect to 151.101.210.132:80 (151.101.210.132), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 151.101.210.132:80:
```

Comment: Did you try to set HTTP_PROXY in the environment where docker daemon is run?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it finally!

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN printf "deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main \n deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN pip3 install awscli

# need gcc to compile psycopg2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install libpq-dev gcc -y \
&& apt-get clean

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install \
    mlflow==1.14.0 \
    psycopg2~=2.8.6  \ 
    boto3

RUN apt-get autoremove -y gcc

RUN mkdir /mlflow/

WORKDIR /mlflow

EXPOSE 8001

CMD mlflow server \
    --host 0.0.0.0 \
    --port 8001 \
    --backend-store-uri "postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:5432/mlflowdb" \
    --default-artifact-root "s3://bucket-eb84c6b0/"
```